# LFTP transfer_log repopulate?

Tags: logging, lftp

Using LFTP my `transfer_log` was getting REALLY large and trying to `cat transfer_log` was taking a really long time. I am hoping to find out that if I remove this `transfer_log` will it be re-created once LFTP starts running again?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to truncate the file using `:>~/.lftp/transfer_log`.

If you just remove the log and an lftp instance has it open, it will grow and occupy disk space until lftp finishes.

BTW, newer lftp versions starting with 4.5.0 have a setting `xfer:max-log-size` to rotate the transfer_log automatically.